# Update pre-compiled files in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

After publishing asp.net web site, I got mant ASP_Web_xxxxx.dll. 
After deploying these files to production server, **how do I know which file to be replaced**, if I modify one codebehind or .aspx file and re-publishing the web site?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are running a web site, and not a web application project. A website doesn't have a project file, and therefore doesn't create a single dll. Instead it created a bunch of smaller dlls. You don't have any control over which classes, etc are in which .dll.

When you deploy your web site, you will need to delete all of these dlls and move all of the new ones over. If you don't do this, you could potentially have 2 dlls that contain the same code, and you will run into issues with code being defined twice when you JIT.

If you can, I recommend you migrate your web site to a Web Application Project, so you only have one .dll you need to worry about. There are several tutorials out there including [this one](http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/Migration2/Migration2.aspx) for VS2005.